# Is this assumption redundant in the proof of Taylor theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

I'm reading Taylor theorem in textbook Analysis I by Amann.

> [image]
>   [image]

and its proof:

> [image]
>   [image]

Here is the Theorem 2.18 used in the proof:

> [image]

---

I read the proof carefully, but could not find where the authors apply the assumption that $D$ is convex. So I think that this assumption is unnecessary.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: Look closely at the definition of the bound on the remainder function.  It requires the line segment from $a$ to $x$ to be in $D.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely comes into play in the definition of $h$, as you assure that $a + t(x-a) $ $\in D$